# Identify part found on garage floor

Tags: part-identification

I don't know if this is a car part or something else, but because I found these laying near the entrance of my garage I thought I would start here.

The pieces feel metallic on what I consider the top (where the engraved "O" shape is) and is attached to some kind of soft, flexible backing.  The two pieces together are connected by this backing and they fold up.  The single piece is facing down and showing this backing.  The single piece measures about 0.75" x 0.6" x .125"

[image: Image of parts]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like wheel weights.  Have you had any tire/wheel work done

Comment: You might want to caveat these as "glue on" or "tape weights" or otherwise "stuck on somehow weights" as opposed to typical wheel weights which go on the side of the rim near the bead of the tire. These weights (if that's what they are) are used on wheels which don't have a real lip on the edge of the rim. They can be used on motorcycles or autos.

Comment: I had new tires put on over a year ago.  I can check with the tire center as soon as possible.  Is there any long-term problem with these not attached to my car?  Thanks for the quick answer!

Comment: No, not really. Im pretty sure they are wheel weights. But since its been over a year, you probably wouldn't have even noticed it if you didn't see it on the floor. You might get a vibration if it is out of balance.

Comment: These are wheel weights used on alloy wheels where the "clip" type can damage the rim. Have you checked the rims to see if there are any patches?

Comment: obviously those are muffler bearings.......

Comment: @moab..lol.... are those stick on, tape on, or glue on muffler bearings